# Finding Which Excel Files a User has opened

Tags: logging

On a Windows 8 PC, is there a way to see which Excel files a user has opened and when? If so, can you please tell me where I would be able to find this information? I'm trying to isolate an issue and this type of information would be incredibly valuable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find out right out of the box....what you'd have to do is enable auditing for the specific file, and then events are logged.  However, beware that auditing sometimes causes processor time, more disk space for the logs.  So generally it is not enabled.